# Qt I want to encode a pointer as a string and decode it later

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt app I'd like to encode a pointer to an object as a string, pass it to another bit of code then decode it so that I can access the object.

This is part of internal drag and drop with a QTreeView.  In my mimeData() method I have:

```
QMimeData * TreeModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData();
    QByteArray encodedData;

    QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    foreach (QModelIndex index, indexes)
    {
        QString colText;
        if (index.isValid()) {
            TreeItem *item = getItem(index);

            // grab the text from each column 
            for(int cc=0; cc < item->columnCount(); cc++ ) {
                colText = item->data(cc).toString();
                stream << colText;
            }
            // add the pointer to the item 
            qDebug() << quint64(&item); 
            stream << quint64(&item);
        }
    }
    mimeData->setData("application/vnd.text.list", encodedData);

    return mimeData;
}
```

The qDebug() line produces a number like 140736277471632 which could be right, but is probably wrong.

How should I encode a pointer as a string so that it can be fed into a stream.  And how should I then decode it and get the pointer to the original object?

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: It is probably not the value you're looking for, as `item` is a local variable. Its address (`&item`) will become unusable as soon as its lifetime ends. It's also the address of a pointer to a `TreeItem`, which doesn't sound very useful.  Aren't you more interested in `item`, which is the pointer to the `TreeItem`?

Comment: I would store not the pointer of the tree item, but its tree path (string). It can be used to find the tree item when you perform drop.

Comment: @Mat - I think its wrong as when I drag and drop another item I get the same number

Comment: You're taking the address of the pointer (i.e. a stack location).

Comment: @ vahancho What is a "tree path"?  Where do I get it?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, I'm interested in Item - I'm trying to get access to item in the associated dropMimeData() method.

Comment: @MichaelVincent, you can calculate it as `<parent_name>/<child_name>/<grandchild_name>` in your tree hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you don't want to take the address of `item`, but its value. It's a pointer, its **value** is the address you're looking for, not its address (which, as already mentioned, is completely irrelevant and dangerous to manipulate once the if block scope is exited).

```
qDebug << qint64(&item);// will print the address this pointer is stored at.
qDebug << qint64(item);// will print the address this pointer is pointing at
```

EDIT: If you want to get the address back from a string into a pointer, read it as a number from a stringstream, i.e.:

```
std::istringstream is{str};
long pointer;//be careful with the size of a pointer in your case.
is >> pointer;
TreeItem* item = reinterpret_cast<TreeItem*>(q);
```

Comment: Although this works, consider @ValentinHeinitz answer as well. Usually you shouldn't handle memory adresses directly, let alone raw pointers.

Comment: yes, I have considered Valentin@s answer.  I have spent far too long already trying to get a pointer from mimeData() to dropMimeDate() in an QAbstractItemModel with no success.  I already pass a string list successfully - adding a string containing the pointer I want seems easy and won't hang around beyond the dropMimeData() method, so, in this case, seems like a reasonable, though imperfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

I would dis-advice doing this.
Serializing objects in strings and de-serializing later makes sense for "moving" objects from one process to another. But within one process, you should pass pointers directly, or wrapped in a container like shared-pointer.

If the only way to pass something is a string, create an instance (e.g. `QMap<QString, YourPointerType>`) where you can register a pointer and access it by a string-name.

If you wrap this map in a class, you can check, if this pointer already exists while registering and if it still exists while retrieving.

Besides, in a models you can store anything you want using User-Roles. You are not limited to store your custom data as mime data.

Comment: I appreciate your "dis-advice" on this, Valentin.  I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to get a "proper" solution working without success.  As I am able to and am already sending a string list from mimeData() to dropMimeData() the approach I have asked about seems acceptable, though imperfect.  Thank you again for your answer.